# Create a list of lists from text-file

Tags: python, file, list

I'm trying to create a list of lists from a text-file. My text-file contains different categories each containing three sentences. It looks kind of like this:

```
Sentence 1 
Sentence 2 
Sentence 3

Sentence 1 
Sentence 2 
Sentence 3

Sentence 1... etc.
```

I want to read these and save each category into a list, and then make a list of those lists/categories. Unfortunally all of my attempts have failed so far, since they cant handle more than one line at a time. The blank line in between the categories is intended as a partition.

Comment: How big is your text file?

Comment: try : `open('abc.txt').read().split('\n\n')`.

Comment: I have five categories so it's small!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    result = [ data[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(data),4)]
```

What is happening is that `data` contains each sentence, `data[i:i+3]` is a category, and I use a list comprehension to make a list of categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
with open('filename') as f:
    lis = [map(str.strip, g) for k,g in 
                             groupby(f, key = lambda x : not x.strip()) if not k]
...     
>>> lis
[['Sentence 1', 'Sentence 2', 'Sentence 3'],
 ['Sentence 1', 'Sentence 2', 'Sentence 3'],
 ['Sentence 1']]
```

If the file is small then this is also fine:

```
with open('abc1') as f:
    print [map(str.strip, x.rsplit('\n'))  for x in f.read().rsplit('\n\n')]
...     
[['Sentence 1', 'Sentence 2', 'Sentence 3'],
 ['Sentence 1', 'Sentence 2', 'Sentence 3'],
 ['Sentence 1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be python one-liner :)

```
result = list(list(l for l in e.split("\n") if l) for e in open("file").read().split("\n\n"))
```

How it works?

`open("file").read().split("\n\n")` opens file, reads it and splits on blocks divided by double-enter.

`list(l for l in e.split("\n") if l)` splits one block (named as `e`) to lines and makes list from it. `if l` is used to eliminate empty lines, if you'd used more than two enters or have got empty lasy line.

The last thing is to connect it - `result = list( expression_2 for e in expression_1)` - We just use `expression_2` on every block from `expression_1` and make list from them. Simply and in one line :)